# Apache Pulsar Rar file

Tags: apache-pulsar

We have been using rar files JCA connector/Resource adapter for JBOSS  to connect to ActiveMQ and looking for similar rar file for Pulsar - Do we have a similar rar file for Pulsar ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for
https://github.com/datastax/pulsar-jms/tree/master/resource-adapter

(I am currently the maintainer of that library)

Answer (score 0):

Which authentication scheme are you using ? In Pulsar it is very common to use JWT authentication.
In that case you have to configure the authPlugin and authParams parameters in the ConnectionFactory.

I hope that this example helps:
https://github.com/eolivelli/pulsar-jms-examples/blob/main/system.properties.auth#L24